# Laravel validation between if checkbox checked

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel Version: 5.7

I want to set a validation. when checkbox is checked, then set a 'between' rule.
just like below.

```
required|integer|between:1,2
```

but when checkbox is not checked is not need between rule like below

```
required|integer
```

I try to use validation, But I don't know how to set.

Inputs

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox">
<input type="number" name="number">
```

Comment: Look there are two checkboxxes with different names. does user need to check both or only a single checkbox

Comment: What version of Laravel 5 are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you are using form request or not, so here is a solution for validation using a [Form request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation)

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class DepartmentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        rules = [];
        if ($this->attributes->has('checkbox')) {
           $rules['key'] = 'required|integer|between:1,2',
        } else {
            $rules['key'] = 'required|integer',
        }

        // Your other validation rules here

        return $rules;
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            // Your custom validation messages here
        ];
    }
}
```

> Remember: You must change the  **key** with the field name you want to validate.

Hope it helps.